# How do I turn off notifications from Windows Defender in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-defender

For some reason Windows Defender keeps popping up notifications (with sound) that became a great disturbance to me. Completely disabling it would be a possible solution, but is there a way to just simply stop it from producing any notification/sound?

EDIT: The malware being reported is [JetBrain CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/)'s installer, which is nuts. Downvoters, I'm curious what you as a programmer would do in this case. Please think things through or at least spend some effort commenting before you attempt to downvote, which is always very cheap to do.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) - why not ask about what it is trying to tell you with these notifications & how to fix the underlying issue?

Comment: @Tetsujin Because I'm a programmer myself and I have confidence that there's nothing wrong? It tries to report JetBrains CLion as malicious software. What do you do in this case? Get rid of CLion instead of this piece of nonsense?

Comment: So many people just downvote without giving any explanation it's ridiculous. I'm a programmer and I know what I'm doing. Windows Defender is trying to report JetBrains CLion's installer as malware, which is crazy. I might just as well turn it off completely but I'd like to see another solution, if possible.

Comment: I'm glad that we were able to help is some small way.  Regarding the down votes, please keep in mind that they are typically a reflection upon the quality of the question itself, not the author or their technical methodologies.  If you had provided the additional information within your original version of the question, it probably would have avoided some/all of those down votes.

Comment: As @Run5k says, the lack of information in the original post was likely the reason for down-votes. We cannot see over your shoulder, we don't know what your usage case is, or the depth & breadth of your CV. We have only the Question to go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remember that if you are consistently seeing notification from Windows Defender, there might be something wrong within your operating system that needs your attention.  It would probably be wise to perform a system scan, and possibly get a "second opinion" scan from another prominent security application like [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/).

That being said, if you really want to disable the notifications you have a couple of options.  You could temporarily use the **Quiet Hours** function:

1. Press <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
2. Click on the **Quiet Hours** box to enable this mode

   [image: Quiet Hours]
3. When you are done, click on **Quiet Hours** again turn off this function

You could also try turning off that specific notification group:

1. Press <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
2. Right-click either the notification itself or the group name and select on **Turn off notifications for this group**

   [image: Turn off notifications for this group]

Once again, I urge you to proceed with caution.  Turning off your security software notifications can lead to even bigger problems!

(Sources:  [How to Turn On or Off Quiet Hours in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/18273-quiet-hours-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) and [How to Turn On or Off App Notifications in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4111-notifications-apps-turn-off-windows-10-a.html))

Comment: Thanks, this is some useful information. I never noticed that Windows has a "quiet hour" functionality. It should work by stopping the sound from being produced.

Comment: As of the notification itself, I'm a programmer and I know what I'm doing. Windows Defender is trying to report JetBrains CLion's installer as malware, which is crazy. I might just as well turn it off completely but I'd like to see another solution, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Press the windows key + I, then select update and security, on the left select windows defender. Go down to enhanced notifications and turn this off. That should prevent any non-serious notifications from coming through. This would be the best option to prevent any serious trouble from going unnoticed.

Directions here:
http://www.ghacks.net/2016/08/05/manage-windows-defender-notifications/

Edit: Add an exclusion for JetBrains CLion.

Comment: Unfortunately 1. I think Windows Defender is trying to report the installer of JetBrains CLion as malware, which is nonsense but unfortunately it thinks it's "serious notification". 2. That option doesn't seem to exist any more in the current version of Windows 10.

Comment: You could try adding an exclusion to JetBrains CLion if that's the only thing throwing a flag.

Comment: Also this is still an option on Windows 10 pro. What version are you using? Maybe it's only on the pro version

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Thanks! I don't need a daily reminder to tell me that my PC is clean.